# How to replace Tensorflow1 ConfigProto in Tensorflow2?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've the following code to set tensorflow config but it's not valid in tensorflow2. Wondering how to rewrite in Tensorflow 2.

```
config = 
tf.ConfigProto(graph_options=tf.GraphOptions(optimizer_options=tf.OptimizerOptions(opt_level=tf.OptimizerOptions.L0)))
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/ConfigProto) instead.